# Move one folder up in nant script

Tags: nant

i'm not an expert of Nant, so i'll have to ask this redicolus question.

i have a variable called svn.source.root which point to c:\folderA\FolderB\FolderC

how can i make svn.source.root.modified variable to point to 2 folders up? i.e, folderA

Obviously, the following didn't work:

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
${svn.source.root.modified}\..\..\
```

Comment: nope, this doesn't work either.....if i "Echo" the result, it doesn't show me the correct path.

Comment: this should work.  when you "echo" you will get "c:\folderA\FolderB\FolderC\..\" but when you actually use the path it will work appropriately and point at FolderB.

Comment: @Or A is absolutely right - this *doesn't* work. I didn't spot it at first, but lo and behold, her/his property syntax was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the property syntax. The `$` must be in front of the `{}`:

```
<project default="test">

    <property name="svn" value="c:\users\peter" />

    <target name="test">
        <echo message="${svn}" />
        <echo message="${svn}\..\..\" />
        <echo message="${path::get-full-path(svn + '\..\..\')}" />
    </target>

</project>
```